# Not able to figure out how to use children and first function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to write a scrape function from dictionary.com in which I am trying to get the word and it's pronunciation. 
I have this div that i need to fetch the data from but I am unable to, not sure what I am doing wrong. I am fetching other div's data(which is a word) just fine but this particular div(pronunciation )...no. New to jquery, node.js. Anything in the right direction would be great.

this is what I have tried which is working on other div just fine.(to get the 'word' from a div working fine but when i come to get the pronunciation it doesn't work)

```js
$('.header-row-header-extras-pronounce-pronset').filter(function() {
  var data = $(this);
  pronunciation += data.children().first().text();

  console.log("prp: " + pronunciation);
  json.pronunciation = pronunciation;
})
```

```html
<div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
  <div>
    <span class="pron spellpron" style="display: inline;">[<span class="dbox-bold">ak</span>-tiv]</span>
    <span class="pron ipapron" style="display: none;">/ˈæk tɪv/ </span>
    <span class="pre-def-data"> </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="prontoggle pronounce-button pronounce-Spell-button">Spell</button>
    <button class="syllable-button syllable-button-off" data-header="1">Syllables</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told about this? Not understand question at all.But this may be help you
[jFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/gghzj5pe/)

```js
var pronunciation = [];
$('.spellpron .dbox-bold').each(function(){
 pronunciation.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(pronunciation);
```

```html
<div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
    <div>
                    <span class="pron spellpron" style="display: inline;">[<span class="dbox-bold">ak</span>-tiv] </span>
            <span class="pron ipapron" style="display: none;">/ˈæk tɪv/ </span>
                            <span class="pre-def-data"> </span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button class="prontoggle pronounce-button pronounce-Spell-button">Spell</button>
            <button class="syllable-button syllable-button-off" data-header="1">Syllables</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
    <div>
                    <span class="pron spellpron" style="display: inline;">[<span class="dbox-bold">ak</span>-tiv] </span>
            <span class="pron ipapron" style="display: none;">/ˈæk tɪv/ </span>
                            <span class="pre-def-data"> </span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button class="prontoggle pronounce-button pronounce-Spell-button">Spell</button>
            <button class="syllable-button syllable-button-off" data-header="1">Syllables</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
    <div>
                    <span class="pron spellpron" style="display: inline;">[<span class="dbox-bold">ak</span>-tiv] </span>
            <span class="pron ipapron" style="display: none;">/ˈæk tɪv/ </span>
                            <span class="pre-def-data"> </span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button class="prontoggle pronounce-button pronounce-Spell-button">Spell</button>
            <button class="syllable-button syllable-button-off" data-header="1">Syllables</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
    <div>
                    <span class="pron spellpron" style="display: inline;">[<span class="dbox-bold">ak</span>-tiv] </span>
            <span class="pron ipapron" style="display: none;">/ˈæk tɪv/ </span>
                            <span class="pre-def-data"> </span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button class="prontoggle pronounce-button pronounce-Spell-button">Spell</button>
            <button class="syllable-button syllable-button-off" data-header="1">Syllables</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
    <div>
                    <span class="pron spellpron" style="display: inline;">[<span class="dbox-bold">ak</span>-tiv] </span>
            <span class="pron ipapron" style="display: none;">/ˈæk tɪv/ </span>
                            <span class="pre-def-data"> </span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button class="prontoggle pronounce-button pronounce-Spell-button">Spell</button>
            <button class="syllable-button syllable-button-off" data-header="1">Syllables</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
    <div>
                    <span class="pron spellpron" style="display: inline;">[<span class="dbox-bold">ak</span>-tiv] </span>
            <span class="pron ipapron" style="display: none;">/ˈæk tɪv/ </span>
                            <span class="pre-def-data"> </span>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button class="prontoggle pronounce-button pronounce-Spell-button">Spell</button>
            <button class="syllable-button syllable-button-off" data-header="1">Syllables</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. This:

   ```
   $('.header-row-header-extras-pronounce-pronset')
   ```

   looks for elements with the *single class* `header-row-header-extras-pronounce-pronset`. But your div doesn't have a single class with that name, it has multiple classes with various parts of that name. To search for multiple classes on an element, you use multple class selectors tied together:

   ```
   $(".header-row.header-extras.pronounce.pronset")
   // Note ------^-------------^---------^
   ```
2. `filter` is for creating a subset of a set of elements. If you're not using the return value of it, use `each` instead.
3. `json.pronunciation = pronunciation;` will *overwrite* `json.pronunciation` each time the callback is run, so you'll end up with only the last one. Without more context, we can't tell you how to fix that, but I thought I should flag it up.

Comment: So yes, that was my question if I have to get the data from for example this class="pron spellpron"  class, how would i go about that

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is selecting one long class, where the mark-up has separate classes.

For the mark-up:

```
<div class="header-row header-extras pronounce pronset">
```

Use this selector:

```
$('.header-row.header-extras.pronounce.pronset').
```

Select elements in jQuery just as you would select them with CSS.